# How to repair elementary OS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I was installing **Google Chrome** on my elementary OS from installer and due to unmet dependencies i run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Don't know what happened i just it was saying

```
removing Pantheon-files
```

and as a result now i am not able to use elementary OS.
As every time i start elementary OSit shows `login screen` but after logged in it just `hanged` nothing showing only `wallpaper` of login screen!!

No i am totally stuck i read somewhere that i should create a live CD on USB then bootup with USB and try to install it again then installer will show `repair` option!
i tried it but repair option is not showing!

now i am very dishearted dont know how to get back my elementary OS or i will have to remove it and then reinstall it?? kindly if its possible to repair elementary OS.
Thanks a lot!

I have installed elementary OS with **Windows 7** dual boot!

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and addd output of `apt-cache policy "pantheon*"`

Comment: Google Chrome didn't break my freya

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you unistalled parts of your desktop.

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop` should do the trick.

BTW you can install chromium from the official repositories.

Comment: let me check thanks for ur reply u r only who replied have tried on stackoverflow and others thanksssssssss

Comment: it was not working so i did `sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop` then it says already in a newer version then i reboot still facing same problem now what should i do?

Comment: Please copy the entire command from the answer.  You need to set the flag - - reinstall as well

Comment: i did it but it did not work @Soundsphere kindly help

Answer (score 0):

after fiddeling with drivers I lost the system settings object in Elemtary OS 5.1

This command resolved it. Thanks @Marc-Aurel Zent

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop
```